# AccessViolationException caused by Workflow.Invoker

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have approximately 12,000 records.

In one of my workflow activities, I interate through all 12,000 records and manually call another Activity on each record.

The line looks like:

```
IDictionary<string, object> results = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(childActivity, args);
```

On about the 11,500th record, I get AccessViolationException with the message that I've reached protected memory.

I can see the memory consumption rising in the Task Manager's Performance tab.

How do I keep the above code from increasing memory on each record interation ultimately conserving memory?

Thanks,
Joshua

Comment: Can you post the full error message, and that of any inner exception; also can you post the stacktrace, as well as more code and a clear indication of which line of code is executed when the exception is raised?

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking a brand new workflow within a different workflow?

Ditch this.  Create a NativeActivity and within the [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781091.aspx) method schedule your child Activity (that workflow) using [NativeActivityContext.ScheduleFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987633.aspx).  In the callback, do what you need to with the result and then schedule the next record.

Comment: great suggestion, but this won't work for what I need it to do. let's, for simplicity sake, say i have a `List<int> options = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}` and for each record of a **DataContext** I want to get the options chosen and do some manipulation, then save back to the object in the current context `foreach (var record in records) 
{ 
    _context.ScheduleFunc...(GetOptions); 
    // do some manipulations to the object 

    DataContext.SaveChanges(); 
}`

then the OnCompletedCallback is called, but... Once the scheduled workflow is called, the context/record is lost.

Comment: again, the datacontext is lost and there are other items in the foreach loop that the manipulations rely on, so i need to somehow execute the child workflow while in context and retrieve the results.  That's why i was using WorkflowInvoker.Invoke() to get the returned results and use them.

Comment: @Joshua: Your issue is with your DataContext becoming disconnected.  Running one workflow within another is just a hack, in your case.  Its not a solution to your actual problem.  I can assure you that WF4 doesn't "lose" anything.  Even when serialized/deserialized complex object graph references are restored correctly.  You need to figure out how to reconnect your DataContext and re-associate your models with this new context.  Or go a different route.  Imagine how much easier this would be without EF?  Am not a fan of ORMs, they usually fail.